# javassist_123 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-envers

There is application on Spring4+ jpa + websphere8.5.5.13

I added envers for make historical for entities, and there is error message when try to get this history

> javassist_123 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

But there is correct work on tomcat server, so, pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <hb.enity.manager>4.2.21.Final</hb.enity.manager>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SERVLET-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JACKSON AND XML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--APACHE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

hibernate propeties are:

```
private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field", true);



properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
    properties.put("useSSL", false);
    properties.put("requireSSL", false);
    properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
    properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
    properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
    properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
    return properties;
}
```

Is somebody met this problem?

Comment: OK, run mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose and see what you get from there. In some of your libs, you are using javaassist version lower than  3.16.1-GA.

Comment: @MS90 No, there is only one dependency org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0:compile

Comment: OK, so this jar lib is uncompatible with your code. Try changing it to lower or current GA version. Don't use compiled at all. You might have messed something up while compiling.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @MS90 3.22.0-GA already in pom. Do you mean get from maven some older version?

Comment: Yes, use some other version than that.

Comment: @MS90 tried with version <version>3.15.0-GA</version> and there is 

NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/Proxy

Answer (score -2):

Solved by migrating from

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is **not** a solution primarily because you should never use a version of `hibernate-envers` that differs from `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager`.  These artifacts are built together and should be deployed with the same version to avoid any runtime compatibility issues.   Hibernate 4.2.21 depends on Javassist version 3.18.1-GA, which you can find on maven central.

Comment: @NarosI already said that solution with javassist 3.18 not working, and other different versions too.

Comment: Then you need to check your dependency tree for your environment and see what is potentially causing the conflict because it seems you have some other library that is forcing a dependency to use incompatible versions.